# is it possible to share a datastore between multiple GAE applications

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bigtable

I like to work with data saved in one GAE application in other GAE applications. 
Basically share the datastore between multiple web applications in Google App Engine (Python) Development and Production.

Also if possible with:
http://localhost:####/_ah/admin/datastore
I like to view data in other applications not runnings and/or running on one screen?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can five different GAE sites all share a common datastore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488744/can-five-different-gae-sites-all-share-a-common-datastore)

Answer (score 6):

Nope, datastores are totally contained within the application.  There is no direct sharing of data from one app to another.

You **could** however expose a web service to make data from one application available to another, using REST for example.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the core problem here is that you would like to share the data between two applications hosted on GAE. There are two ways to do that.

1. You could use Google Cloud Datastore to store the information. This gives you more flexibility as you can have different services accessing datastore. You could even have something running on google compute engine and communicating with datastore.
2. Use google appengine modules. All modules share the same datastore. In your case each module could be a different application.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

No, a datastore can only be accessed by one application (but that app can serve up multiple sites).

If you want Google to allow multiple applications to directly access the same datastore then you should star this issue:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1300

Unfortunately the way this issue is written is a bit ambiguous, but I take it to mean 'multiple applications' rather then 'multiple accounts'.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, you can deploy an application with another version and language - but with the same id, and [be able to access its datastore concurrently](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#pythonandjava)