# What are some inexpensive options to deploy hobby play apps

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, playframework

I have a total of 5 Play applications that I have been working on my spare time. They are small projects, serious enough to be published to the world yet not enough to invest large sums of money. I would anticipate a maximum of 10k visits per month, they are read only (information comes out of a database, nothing comes in).

What are some good inexpensive options to deploy these 5 websites? They will have 5 different domain names.

Thanks,

Comment: Digital Ocean has at time of writing a US$10 per month options that are making us very happy. If that's too much, try Heroku - we have deployed some test apps there on their free instances, although we did hit limitations quite quickly at the free levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pay for the 5 domains regardless of the option.

Note: I can only speak for GAE, I have no experience with AWS.

In GAE you *might* be able to stay within the free quotas:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas

Free quotas are higher for a paid account which *might* be overall more cost-effective than a non-paid account.

If the apps share the DB (not directly possible in GAE at this time, see [is it possible to share a datastore between multiple GAE applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604621/is-it-possible-to-share-a-datastore-between-multiple-gae-applications) and maybe related Q&As) I'd recommend making them just modules of a single app instead of separate apps. All domains would be mapped to that single app and routed to separate modules using a dispatch file.

Comment: If he has 5 separate GAE apps, then free quota includes 24/7 of an instance.  If he has 5 modules of a single app, then he's probably paying for 5 instances and that will cost money, no?

Comment: @Kekito The free 28 instance hrs apply only if using F1 type instances; 15min wasted for each instance lifetime eat into that; everything else being equal running 1 app instead of 5 is roughly equivalent to a free quota of 28h / 5 = ~5h, meaning a MAX extra cost of (28h - 5h) x $0.05 = $1.15 per day for days with extremely unfriendly traffic. Could be preferable to complications and potential extra costs of inter-app communication (other quotas) needed for sharing the DB. Daily budget limits (for which 1 app instead of 5 is also better) can keep costs under control - paid apps only.

Comment: @Kekito 1st statement in previous comment came out wrong, I mean "free quota includes 24/7 of an instance" is applicable only if using F1 type instances.